# how to remove html tag or div from widgEditor input box?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I was using [widgEditor](http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/widgEditor/) for taking user input. When I write something and go next like it automatically shows a div and generate html which I don't want to store.
Suppose when I print the editor text I saw output like

```
"explain" => "<p>fasd</p><div>ds</div><div>fa</div><div><br /></div><div>fs</div><div><br /></div>
```

Though it should give me the output the way i typed means putting image inside of it ..next line etc.

controller code:

```
$error = new Error();
$error->explain =$request->Input(['explain']);
dd($error);
```

How do I get appropriate output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **preg_replace**, something like this:

```
preg_replace("/<div>(.*?)<\/div>/", "$1", $request->Input(['explain']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) method

```
$error->explain = strip_tags($request->Input(['explain']));
```